# How can I test computed properties in VueJS?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, vue.js

I'm using VueJS from Vue CLI. So all my components are in `.vue` format.

In one of my components, I have an array called `fields` in the data section.

```
//Component.vue
data() {
  return {
     fields : [{"name" : "foo", "title" : "Foosteria"}, {"name" : "bar", "title" : "Barrista"}]
  }
}
```

I have a **computed property** that is a subset of `fields`

```
//Component.vue
computed : {
    subsetOfFields () {
       // Something else in component data determines this list
    }
}
```

I've set up all of my unit tests in `jasmine` like this and they work fine.

```
 //Component.spec.js
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import MyComponent from 'Component.vue'
 describe("Component test", function() {
      var myComponentVar = new Vue(MyComponent);
      var vm = myComponentVar.$mount();

      beforeEach(function() {
         vm = myComponentVar.$mount();
      );

      afterEach(function() {
         vm = myComponentVar.$destroy();
      });

      it("First spec tests something", function() {
            ...
       });

 });
```

For everything else, doing something inside the `spec`, then running assertions on the `data` objects works just fine. However, running an assertion on `subsetOfFields` always returns an empty array. Why so? What should I do, in order to be able to test it?

FYI, I even tried nesting the spec inside another `describe` block and then adding a `beforeEach` which initializes the `fields` array. It did not work.

However, initializing `fields` inside the generic `beforeEach` function worked. But I don't want to initialize the `fields` array with that mock data for the other specs.

Comment: This is the component.spec.js for the actual Vue project. You can find what you need in there likely. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/test/unit/features/options/computed.spec.js

Comment: @BertEvans, I already tried the technique in that example. He's initializing the component with the data already in it.

However in line 18 , the data for `a` changes from 1 to 2 and the change is expected in `b` in line 19. I did the same thing but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this link that talks about testing and the section you'll need to look at is the `Vue.nextTick(...)` section

https://alligator.io/vuejs/unit-testing-karma-mocha/

The block I'm talking about is below:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
// The path is relative to the project root.
import TestMe2 from 'src/components/TestMe2';

describe('TestMe2.vue', () => {
  ...
  it(`should update when dataText is changed.`, done => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(TestMe2);

    const comp = new Constructor().$mount();

    comp.dataProp = 'New Text';

    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      expect(comp.$el.textContent)
        .to.equal('New Text');
      // Since we're doing this asynchronously, we need to call done() to tell Mocha that we've finished the test.
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.